# Steam Callbacks Trigger Warning During Compile In Linux / GCC

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, steam, steamworks-api

I've been working on my Steamworks integration for a while now and every time I compile on Linux, all of my callbacks trigger this warning.  One for each so there is a wall of that. That being said, the callbacks work perfectly fine.

```
module.h: In member function 'virtual void Steam::CCallbackInternal__steam_api_call_completed::Run(void*)':
module.h:667:18: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type 'Steam' is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
  667 |   STEAM_CALLBACK(Steam, _steam_api_call_completed, SteamAPICallCompleted_t);
sdk/public/steam/steam_api_internal.h:39:58: note: in expansion of macro '_STEAM_CALLBACK_3'
   39 | #define _STEAM_CALLBACK_HELPER( _1, _2, SELECTED, ... )  _STEAM_CALLBACK_##SELECTED
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sdk/public/steam/steam_api_common.h:99:2: note: in expansion of macro '_STEAM_CALLBACK_SELECT'
   99 |  _STEAM_CALLBACK_SELECT( ( __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3 ), ( /**/, thisclass, func, __VA_ARGS__ ) )
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
module.h:667:3: note: in expansion of macro 'STEAM_CALLBACK'
  667 |   STEAM_CALLBACK(Steam, _steam_api_call_completed, SteamAPICallCompleted_t);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
module.h: In member function 'virtual void Steam::CCallbackInternal__steam_shutdown::Run(void*)':
module.h:668:18: warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type 'Steam' is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]
  668 |   STEAM_CALLBACK(Steam, _steam_shutdown, SteamShutdown_t);
sdk/public/steam/steam_api_internal.h:39:58: note: in expansion of macro '_STEAM_CALLBACK_3'
   39 | #define _STEAM_CALLBACK_HELPER( _1, _2, SELECTED, ... )  _STEAM_CALLBACK_##SELECTED
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sdk/public/steam/steam_api_common.h:99:2: note: in expansion of macro '_STEAM_CALLBACK_SELECT'
   99 |  _STEAM_CALLBACK_SELECT( ( __VA_ARGS__, 4, 3 ), ( /**/, thisclass, func, __VA_ARGS__ ) )
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
module.h:668:3: note: in expansion of macro 'STEAM_CALLBACK'
  668 |   STEAM_CALLBACK(Steam, _steam_shutdown, SteamShutdown_t);
```

While the callbacks work, wondering what is causing these warnings and perhaps how to fix them.

I am compiling in Ubuntu Linux 19.10 with GCC / G++ 9.2.1, for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I had to silence them with

```cpp
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Winvalid-offsetof"

// my code

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```